# Почему не работает gulp после обновления до 4 версии?

Tags: gulp, gulp4

Обновил gulp и таски, но выдает ошибку AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    scss = require('gulp-sass'); //Подключаем Sass пакет
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'); // Подключаем Browser Sync
    svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin'); // svgo для редактирования svg
    concat = require('gulp-concat'), // Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
    uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs'); // Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'), // Подключаем пакет для минификации CSS
    rename = require('gulp-rename'); // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
    del = require('del'); // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок
    tinypng = require('gulp-tinypng-unlimited');
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');// Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов
    cache       = require('gulp-cache'); // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования



gulp.task('scss', function(){ // Создаем таск "sass"
    // return gulp.src('app/less/**/*.less') // Берем источник
         return gulp.src(['app/sass/style.scss', "app/sass/libs.scss"]) // Берем источник
        // .pipe(scss()) // Преобразуем Sass в CSS посредством gulp-sass
        .pipe(scss({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', scss.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) // Создаем префиксы
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('svgmin', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/img/svg/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img'));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { // Создаем таск browser-sync
    browserSync({ // Выполняем browser Sync
        server: { // Определяем параметры сервера
            baseDir: 'app' // Директория для сервера - app
        },
        notify: false // Отключаем уведомления
    });
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([ // Берем все необходимые библиотеки
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', // Берем jQuery
        'app/libs/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' // Берем Magnific Popup
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs.min.js')) // Собираем их в кучу в новом файле libs.min.js
        .pipe(uglify()) // Сжимаем JS файл
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')); // Выгружаем в папку app/js
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify()) // Сжимаем JS файл
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // Добавляем суффикс .min
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')); // Выгружаем в папку app/js
});

gulp.task('css-min', ['scss'], function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/css/style.css', 'app/css/normalize.css', 'app/css/libs.css']) // Выбираем файл для минификации
        .pipe(cssnano()) // Сжимаем
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // Добавляем суффикс .min
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')); // Выгружаем в папку app/css
});

gulp.task('img', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*.@(png|jpg|jpeg)')
    .pipe(tinypng())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.paralle('scss')); // Наблюдение за sass файлами
    // Наблюдение за другими типами файлов
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); // Наблюдение за HTML файлами в корне проекта
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); // Наблюдение за JS файлами в папке js
});

gulp.task('clear', function () {
    return cache.clearAll();
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'browser-sync', 'css-min', 'scripts', 'js', 'img'));











gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del.sync('dist'); // Удаляем папку dist перед сборкой
});


gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('clean', 'scss', 'scripts'), function() {

    var buildCss = gulp.src([ // Переносим CSS стили в продакшен
        'app/css/style.css',
        'app/css/style.min.css',
        'app/css/normalize.min.css',
        'app/css/libs.min.css'
        ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))

    var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*') // Переносим шрифты в продакшен
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))

    var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*') // Переносим скрипты в продакшен
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))

    var buildImg = gulp.src('app/img/*') // Переносим изображения в продакшен
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))

    var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html') // Переносим HTML в продакшен
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});
```

[image: Ошибка]

[image: package.json]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesyrCZE1bA тут есть ответ

Comment: @xes буквально сейчас по этой инструкции делал

Comment: тогда хз сам еще маленький

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом, а не картинками.